# IDisposable member of WPF Window class

Tags: .net, wpf, idisposable

When I add IDisposable class member to Windows Forms Form class, I add disposing code to Form's Dispose method. What should I do when I add IDisposable class member to WPF Window class, which is not IDisposable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extend your window class so that it has IDisposable, then implement the Dispose() method as before:

```
public class MyWindow : Window, IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Dispose your objects here as before.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Approaches you can use:

- Use `Closed` event on `Window`.
- Implement `IDisposable` interface yourself for this `Window`.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) pattern that hooks into the classes finalizer. This means that your IDisposable member would always get cleared up. The only problem is that you wouldn't know when as it depends on the GC to collect the Window class.

Alternatively you could add an event handler the the `Window.Closed` event and do your disposing there.