# WPF using statement to open another form

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I wrote a C# app in Winforms and am now rewriting it in WPF.  In the Winforms version I used the following to open another window while sending it information and receive information back from it:

```
using (showSelection showSelection1 = new showSelection(listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()))
            {
                showSelection1.ShowDialog();               
                storage1.showID = showSelection1.showID;
                storage1.numOfSeasons = showSelection1.numOfSeasons;

            }
```

This worked fine, I sent the selected item from `listBox2` and received `showID` and `numOfSeasons` using this code in the showSelection form:

```
this.showID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[2, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value);
this.numOfSeasons = dataGridView1[1, dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
this.Close();
```

Now, in the WPF version I try the same thing:

```
using (ShowSelection showSelection = new ShowSelection(showListBox.SelectedItem.ToString()))
            {

            }
```

But inside the `using( )` I get this error:
`ShowSelection: type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'`

I'm not really sure where to do from here.  Can I fix this and still go about it the same way or is there a different way I should be doing this?  The ShowSelection window is just a datagrid with a single button.

Comment: Your ShowSelection window is not implementing IDispoable, implement IDisposable in the window code behind. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450904/idisposable-member-of-wpf-window-class

Comment: dont code wpf like you code winforms... you will miss all the nice stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WPF components don't use Win32 handles (`Window` does, but it self-manages), so they have no need to be `IDisposable`, and you have no need to `Dispose` them or use them in a `using` block.

Once there are no more references to your `Window` it'll be marked for collection by the GC, same as other pure NET components.

In case you want to use it within a `using` block, you can implement `IDisposable` on your window manually, but it's indeed not needed.

In case you want to manually remove resources (and keep using it in a `using` block), then the simplest you can do:

```
public class ShowSelection : Window, IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
      /* here you'd remove any references you don't need */
    }
}
```

But unless there's a need for it, I'd advise against doing so

Comment: Thanks!  I suppose I should look into how I'm actually supposed to get data back from a window.

Comment: @Jrow it should be exactly the same, you just don't use the `using` block, but you do use the `ShowSelection showSelection = new ShowSelection(showListBox.SelectedItem.ToString())`. However if using WPF I'd look into the MVVM pattern and use a ViewModel to have your data bound to (that'd be way outside the scope of this question though)

Answer (score 1):

it's simply says that ShowSelection class do not derive from IDisposable
so use it without the using:

ShowSelection showSelection = new ShowSelection(showListBox.SelectedItem.ToString());

and than access the properties you need to:
showSelection.#####